# Magento 2: Default Values for `system.xml` Configuration

Tags: magento2, module, configuration, system.xml

In Magento 1, it was possible to

1. Configuration a user interface for the System Configuration section in `etc/system.xml` files
2. Set default values for those fields in the `etc/config.xml` files

Behind the scenes Magento would load data from `core_config_data`, and if nothing was set, would default to the values set globally in `etc/config.xml`. (simplified version — it's a [little more complicated than that](http://alanstorm.com/magento_loading_config_variables))

Can the same thing be done in Magento 2?  I know it's possible to configure UI elements via `system.xml` — but is it possible to set default values for these settings?  If so, where or how should these values be configured?

Comment: I am developing an extension where in the ADMIN store>>configuration my extension setting i want to put attribute draggable and sortable list and therefore i need to set custom template for this particular field, so is there any way i can put custom template phtml file inside system.xml?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

yes, Magento 2 still allows you to define the default values inside a configuration file.
namespace\modulename\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
        <default>
            <sectionname>
                <groupname>
                    <fieldid>1</fieldid>
                </groupname>
            </sectionname>
        </default>
    </config>
```

System configuration system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

    <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
        <system>
            <tab id="namespace_tab" translate="label" sortOrder="1">
                <label>COnfig Title</label>
            </tab>
            <section id="sectionname" translate="label" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
    showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Some Title</label>
                <tab>namespace_tab</tab>
                <resource>Namespace_Modulename::system_config</resource>
                <group id="groupname" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" 
    showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Some Configuration</label>
                    <field id="fieldid" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" 
    showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                        <label>Enable in frontend</label>
                        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    </field>
                 </group>   
            </section>
        </system>
    </config>
```

Comment: Note that sectionname, groupname, and fieldid all correlate to the tag id of each section.

Comment: how can we get this default value in .php file

Comment: @AnandOntigeri use
`$this->scopeConfig->getValue(
   $path,
   \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
  );`
Where `$this->scopeConfig` must be instantiated in class __construct() method.

`\Magento\Framework\Cache\ConfigInterface $scopeConfig`

Comment: Is it possible to get the default values instead of the configured values? Vasilii's comment gives the current value, but I want to compare the current configuration of a site to the default values (and if possible, reset it). Can that be done without loading and reading the `config.xml` manually ?

Comment: @JaccoAmersfoort The default values are only accessible until they are overwritten. Magento 2 stores the system values in the core_config_data table and does not store the default values separate from the current value.

Comment: @Eirik Thanks! Then I will have to read the `config.xml` file directly and get the values that way

Comment: Note that the default value will not show up if there is already a value for the field and if your module was not reinstalled. Steps for both : `delete from core_config_data where path = "sectionname/groupname/fieldname";` and ` delete from setup_module where module = 'Dpc_Loyalty';` with `bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Answer (score 8):

`Magento2` allow you to set default value same like `Magento1`. When you look at the contact module from `Magento2`,

`system.xml` for contact module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>
        <section id="contact" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="100" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <label>Contacts</label>
            <tab>general</tab>
            <resource>Magento_Contact::contact</resource>
            <group id="contact" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Contact Us</label>
                <field id="enabled" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Enable Contact Us</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                    <backend_model>Magento\Contact\Model\System\Config\Backend\Links</backend_model>
                </field>
            </group>
            <group id="email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="50" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <label>Email Options</label>
                <field id="recipient_email" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Send Emails To</label>
                    <validate>validate-email</validate>
                </field>
                <field id="sender_email_identity" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Sender</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
                </field>
                <field id="email_template" translate="label comment" type="select" sortOrder="30" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Email Template</label>
                    <comment>Email template chosen based on theme fallback when "Default" option is selected.</comment>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Template</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

and  `config.xml` for the contact module

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
            <contact>
                <enabled>1</enabled>
            </contact>
            <email>
                <recipient_email>
                    <![CDATA[hello@example.com]]>
                </recipient_email>
                <sender_email_identity>custom2</sender_email_identity>
                <email_template>contact_email_email_template</email_template>
            </email>
    </default>
</config>
```

---

If we want to set default value, then we have to match its id like

`<section id="contact">`
`<group id="contact">`
`<field id="enabled">`

then it becomes

```
 <default>
     <contact>
           <contact>
                  <enabled>1</enabled>
           </contact>
     </contact>
 </default>
```