# Magento 2 System Config Enabled Yes/No

Tags: magento2, module, extensions

I would like to add module On/Off option in Configuration for custom extension.

I have used below code and add into my **system.xml** but when I select option No module is not off.

```
<field id="active" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
       <label>Enabled</label>
       <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
</field>
```

Is there any anther code I have to do in other file ?

Or is there wrong in this code ?

Comment: Have you remove var/generataion folder

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: are you add condition in xml file
 ifconfig="sectionid/groupid/fieldid"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try below snippet:

```
<group id="test" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="350" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="0">
    <label>Your Title</label>
    <field id="enable_module" translate="label" type="select" showInDefault="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Enabled</label>
        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
    </field>
</group>
```

Comment: hi @Ashish, how to show default as No

Comment: Also can you tell me how to read this value?

Comment: Refre this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/90797/62614

Comment: <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
 this line  show the selelect  button option yes/no.. can you guyes please tell me  how can button knows module should be off while selelect **no** and on while select **yes**.