# Magento 2: I need to add default text field value in system configuration

Tags: magento2

Need to add default text field value in system configuration.
 Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: you need to add and save text field into magento 2 admin configuration section using your custom module?  am i right?

Comment: I need to show the default text field value in system configuration field

Comment: Check my answer and let me known if it is working or not.

Answer (score 2):

Please change file as follow

> app\code\Abc\Abandon\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd"> <system> 

     <section id="abc_abandon" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="23" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
        <group id="abandon_cart" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
          <field id="abandon_cart_media_path" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="1" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                    <label>Catalog media files path</label>

            </field>
         </group>
    </section> </system> </config>
```

> app\code\Abc\Abandon\etc\config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <abc_abandon><!-- tag of the system.xml section -->
            <abandon_cart><!-- tag of the system.xml group -->
                <abandon_cart_media_path>path</abandon_cart_media_path><!-- tag of the system.xml field -->
            </abandon_cart>
        </abc_abandon>
    </default>

</config>
```

i have change **noNamespaceSchemaLocation** for both file

Please refer this :- [Magento 2: Default Values for `system.xml` Configuration](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/90795/magento-2-default-values-for-system-xml-configuration)

Comment: This is only working for enable disable fields not for text fields

Answer (score 2):

Please follow below step to store default text field value.

Change file as follow

> app\code\Vendor\Abandon\etc\adminhtml\system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
<system>
    <tab id="Vendor" translate="label" sortOrder="550">
        <label>Vendor</label>
    </tab>
    <section id="vendor_abandon" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0" type="text" translate="label" sortOrder="100">
        <label>Abandoned Cart Settings</label>
        <tab>vendor</tab>
        <resource>Vendor_Abandon::abandon_settings</resource>

        <group id="abandon_cart" showInDefault="1" showInStore="0" showInWebsite="0" sortOrder="20">
            <label>General Configuration</label>
            <field id="abandon_cart_media_path" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="10" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="0" showInStore="0">
                <label>Catalog media files path</label>
            </field>
        </group>
    </section>
</system>
```

> app\code\Vendor\Abandon\etc\config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <vendor_abandon>
            <abandon_cart>
                <abandon_cart_media_path>Test</abandon_cart_media_path>
            </abandon_cart>
        </vendor_abandon>
    </default>
</config>
```

> You can set your default value in `<abandon_cart_media_path>Test</abandon_cart_media_path>` as per your requirement. i just added as test default value.

Comment: Ok, But can you tell me why should i delete?

Comment: I am updated code. Please check.

Comment: below your question you will get delete option

Comment: ok , so first you need to tell the the guys to delete their answer from your question

Answer (score 1):

Please correct below code in your `config.xml`

> app\code\Abc\Abandon\etc\config.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <abc_abandon> <!-- section ID -->
            <abc_cart> <!-- group ID -->
                <abandon_cart_media_path>0</abandon_cart_media_path> <!-- field ID -->
            </abc_cart>
        </abc_abandon>
    </default>
</config>
```

Clear Magento cache once and check.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: What you have changed. code is similar

Comment: I think your group ID is not correct in your question. Please review that once.

Comment: This is typo mistake. But it's correct in my code

Comment: updated group id